# Having function choose largest number of given ones

Tags: c, function, max

Computer gives me wrong result when choosing the largest number of three given numbers.
I'm not sure if this is possible way to code this program. I'm new to C, but when we learned about Pascal in school, this is roughly how we made the program choose the largest number (by introducing another variable, in my case X).
Sorry if this was posted before, can't seem to find it.

```
int max(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    int result;
    int X;
    if (num1>num2) {
        num1 = X;
    } else {
        num2 = X;
    }
    if (num3>X) {
        num3 = result;
    } else {
        X = result;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Result: %d", max(4, 10, 15));
    return 0;
}
```

I'd expect it to show me MAX number of 15, but it shows me some random, big number.
NOTE: I'm also having problems with code format

Comment: your indentation is weird and easily confusing. Also learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: max(num1,max(num2,num3));

Comment: In C you have "stdlib.h" you have macros called min and max, you can pass these any types you like, result = max(123, 12); or result = min(123,12);

Comment: @SPlatten who told you that there are `min` and `max` in stdlib.h? There are no standard macros that are not in upper case, and there are definitely no macro for taking min and max, unless you're using Windows.h without `NOMINMAX`

Comment: @phuclv, either stdlib.h or stdio.h, one of those, at least they were when I started programming in C back in the mid 80's.

Comment: @SPlatten no, they were never in any C standards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C it is like in Pascal: the target of an assignment is on the left of the assignment operator ('=' in C, ':=' in Pascal) and the expression to assign is on the right.

Just swap both sides and it works.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here: `if(num3>X) {num3 = result;}`. You are setting that `num3` argument will have the value of the variable `result`. The same you do in the code of this one.

When you declare local variables like `result`and `X`, they will have an initial random value of what is in the offset of stack correspondent to these variables addresses. Thus you are not changing this default random value that variable `result`.

I think what you wanted to do is to just `result = num3;`.

Comment: Yeah, I just realised what I had done... I rotated them and didn't notice because I was too sleepy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
int max(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    // suppose num1=11,num2=7, num3=13
    int result;
    if(num1>num2){result = num1;} //as 11>7, result=11
        else {result = num2;}

    // now result=11
    if(num3>result) {result = num3;} //13>11, result=13

    return result; // returned 13
}

int main()
{
    printf("Result: %d", max(4, 10, 15));
    return 0;
}
```

This code should work the way you intended.

In your code, the problem is in the following lines:

```
if(num1>num2){num1 = X;}
```

Here what you are doing is, if num1>num2, then you assign the variable holding one of the numbers the value stored in `X`.

As you never stored a value in `X`, `num1` will get a garbage value.

I am not sure how it happens in `pascal`, but in `C` value is assigned from quantity at right hand side to the variable at left hand side.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I was sleepy so I never figured out why it's not working, it seemed like a simple application, we did tons of that in school in Lazarus.

Answer (score 1):

Other comments and answers have indicated why the OPs posted code did not result in the correct answer.

The following direct approach is simple, quick, but does not scale well when there are a lot of numbers to choose from.

```
int max(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    int X = num1;

    if( num2 > X )
        X = num2;

    if( num3 > X )
        X = num3;

    return X;
}
```

Comment: Well in that case, it would be a good idea to show the same func with variadic arguments.

Comment: Yeah, actually never thought of it. Thanks, will keep that in mind! :)